# How to connect checkboxes in MS-ACCESS with specific columns

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm a beginner developer and I need your help. I have Access database ( records were imported form Excel) and I made a form with checkboxes which names are the same like name of columns in database. I would like to connect them(I mean checkboxes) with this columns(from database) and make a button for printing only checked columns.

Comment: Fields of a query object cannot be dynamic. What you describe seems to be you want to change the fields in a query. Doing that would require VBA code manipulating QueryDefs collection to modify a query object. If instead you want to apply filter criteria with the 'checked' fields, that also will require VBA code. Are these fields yes/no type?

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html and http://allenbrowne.com/NoYesNo.html

Comment: I have this form: http://zapisz.net/images/706_untitled.jpg
The effect which I want to gain is: i have all records, then i filter records from e.g Location, the program found all records where location = e.g London, and then i click button print/export which forward me to form where I can checked columns i would like to print e.g, department, location, PCNumber

Comment: So you do want to specify the fields to include in query object. As I said, requires VBA code. I already mentioned using QueryDefs collection to modify query structure. Or could run MakeTable query every time you want to export. I really don't recommend doing either because these are database design changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple in MS-Office 2016 to add Check Box. Open Ms Access, Locate your Table, Select Column where you want to add heck Box, Locate Field tab in Ribbon where you will find Yes/No under add & Delete Section. For reference screenshot is attached.[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot mentioned that this checkboxes I have in separate form which will be connected with form used for filter records. I will use it to print checked, filtered columns. The effect which I want to gain is: i have all records, then i filter records from e.g Location, the program found all records where location = e.g London, and then i click button print/export which forward me to form where I can checked columns i would like to print e.g, department, location, PCNumber.

Comment: You print forms? Use reports!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I have checked it is fine working here is entry table
 [image: This image is shows entry of data]
 Here is Report Print Preview
[image: Here is print preview of Form]